# Where are variable names is stored after compiling?

Tags: c, memory

When I write,

`int number = 5;`

I understand 5 is stored in memory at some address. Where is the variable name `number` stored?

Comment: It will be stored either in the debug data or it will be discarded.

Comment: after compiling you don't need the name anymore

Comment: It is stored in the compiler memory while it compiles. Afterwards, there is no space for `"number"` anywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After compiling and linking the machine code, the name of the variable is not necessary any more. The machine code just needs to know the location of the variable. Some variables might even be stored in CPU registers, and have no address at all.

If you compile and link without debug flags, the name will not be stored in the resulting executable file.

If you compile and link with debug flags, it depends on the system. Some systems provide a special section in the executable file with some kind of a table, which contains the name and other information like the type, for example. Some systems would store this information in another file, not the executable file.